# Duplicate of a closed question - Where should people go?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

Looking through the unanswered questions I stumbled across [this question about confidence](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4633/how-to-help-my-girlfriend-with-her-lack-of-self-confidence), not being the most confident of people and perhaps looking to share some of my own experiences and what helped me.
After noticing that it was closed as a duplicate I headed over to the [linked question in, well, question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/how-to-help-my-girlfriend-get-her-confidence-back) only to find that it was also closed.

I am very much not disputing the closing of either of these questions, I am sure there are other ways to make an appeal like that, I was just wondering if this is the intended site behaviour?

Currently there is no open question about this topic (*that can be found directly through either question I linked*), and similar questions are likely to be marked and closed as duplicates, as is the SE way.

**What is the appropriate / expected / best practice way, both for a question asker and answerer to deal with situations like this?**

Comment: Did you read the comments below the original closed question?

Comment: On the [duplicate] question, yes. On the [off-topic] question I hadn't read all of them, I have now. While both give good context on why their respective questions were closed, I'm not sure what the take-away should be (especially in relation to my meta-question). That all confidence questions should be off-topic because they are best handled by professionals? That sounds unlikely to be what you mean (and would probably have been more clearly communicated by the question marked as a duplicate having been closed as off-topic instead).

Comment: @Mara The question is marked duplicate so that users would follow the link to read the earlier one. The earlier one was closed for the reasons given there. Any new questions in the similar vein would most likely be closed as a duplicate of the first one.

Comment: The two questions refer to two individuals who seem to have deeper more complex issues than a lack of confidence, the best answer is to seek professional help and therapy because a 200-word answer posted by a stranger, however well-meaning, will always be insufficient. A good answer would entail writing a book, this is a Q&A site and sometimes you have got to know where your limits lie.

Comment: That's not to say the questions or the answers are not helpful, they all are, but you need fully qualified experts to deal with these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MariLouA stated in her comment: The two questions refer to two individuals who seem to have deeper more complex issues than a lack of confidence, the best answer is to seek professional help and therapy because a 200-word answer posted by a stranger, however well-meaning, will always be insufficient. A good answer would entail writing a book, this is a Q&A site and sometimes you have got to know where your limits lie.

Both questions talk about a person having a lack of confidence due to some serious underlying issues: [This one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4633/how-to-help-my-girlfriend-with-her-lack-of-self-confidence) states the most likely reasons being parental abuse- and abandonment. [The other one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/how-to-help-my-girlfriend-get-her-confidence-back) gives severe bullying, physical and verbal abuse as reasons for the lack of self-confidence. These deeper, more complex issues are what makes the questions similar and why they both are closed for 'needing professional help':

> *We can't guarantee that all the answers you will get are from fellow-sufferers. And even if they were, we can't guarantee that they are safe to use. I repeat: In case of a bad answer that actually damages your girlfriend more, we have consequences on our hand that go beyond feeling awkward or embarrassed. – Tinkeringbell Sep 19 at 14:57*

**What is the appropriate / expected / best practice way, both for a question asker and answerer to deal with situations like this?**

For an asker:

- Provide us with enough information so that we can be confident that there are no deeper issues at stake.
- Provide a clear example of where your confidence is lacking. We probably need a specific situation to address, so that the question is about Interpersonal Skills. A lack of confidence to go to the beach in your bikini isn't an interpersonal skill. A lack of confidence to voice your opinion in a specific situation might be. We're still struggling a bit with our scope, so a lot depends on how interpersonal your situation is. I'm afraid that part can only be answered once we see a proposed question.
- Provide us with a goal you want to achieve (closely related to providing a clear example). For example, if you want to gain more confidence to speak out loud in certain situations, state so in your question. The more explicit you can make a question, the less we have to ask you to explain yourself in comments.

For an answerer:

- Check if all of the points above are present. If they are not, the question should probably be put on-hold until the asker has improved their question and provided us with something that doesn't need a book or professional help to answer.
- It's okay to answer a question before it's on-hold, that happens all the time. But if it's put on-hold, please carefully read the argument as to why it was put on-hold. *If you think the reason why it was put on-hold is not a valid one, preferably take the question to meta because we're still a beta site developing our scope, and having a trace of discussion on meta helps us with that.* You can also leave a comment and vote to reopen if you have enough reputation to do so.

That being said, there is actually a third question about self-confidence on this site that is still open: [How to respond to a friend with little to no self confidence and often doesn't feel good about themselves](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/how-to-respond-to-a-friend-with-little-to-no-self-confidence-and-often-doesnt-f)

As you can see, this has no mention of serious underlying issues and thus isn't closed as a duplicate of the other 2.